# Cannot use Picasso and retrofit together

Tags: android, retrofit, proguard, picasso

I'm using `Picasso` and `Retrofit` together in my app. Everything works perfectly in `debug` version, but whenever I try to generate a signed apk I get something like this `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'`

I searched for a while and tried using `-dontwarn retrofit.*` in `proguard-rules.pro`

This isn't working

Comment: Please edit your question and post the entire Gradle Console output, rather than just one line. Most likely, the real problem appears higher in the output than this line.

Comment: Gradle Console Output?

Comment: In Android Studio, the Gradle Console tool is docked by default on the bottom, towards the right. This is the complete text output of the build process.

Answer (score 0):

`Picasso` proguard configuration

```
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
```

`Retrofit` proguard configuration

```
-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
}
```